# Cannot write sorted list into new file.

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a sorted list onto a file. I have 1000 integers that I've sorted in ascending order, but cannot manage to write the new list of ascending numbers into my new file 'results'. I am new to programming and any help would be greatly appreciated.
This is my code so far:

```
def insertion_sort():
    f = open("integers.txt", "r")

    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    print(lines)
    print(type(lines[0]))
    results = list(map(int, lines))
    print(type(results[0]))
    results.sort()
    print(results)


f=open("integers.txt", "r")
lines = f.read().splitlines()
results = list(map(int,lines))
insertion_sort()

value = results.sort()

file_to_save_to = open("results.txt", "w")
file_to_save_to.write(str(value))
file_to_save_to.close()
```

Comment: I've tried that but it says that:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Octavian Rosca\Desktop\Programming\Assignment4\insertionSort.py.py", line 19, in <module>
    value = sort(results)
NameError: name 'sort' is not defined

Comment: my mistake, the function is `sorted()`, not `sort()`, so you can use `sorted(results)`, but as you've used `results.sort()` also works.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is from this line

`value = results.sort()`

the sort method of a list doesn't return anything, it modifies the list in place.

Instead you should use `sorted`

```
value = sorted(results)
```

or the list directly as `results` without storing the return value of it's sort method

```
results.sort()`
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `insertion_sort()` which is a function that performs the operation, but doesn't yet return anything. You'll want to return the `results` by simply adding the return statement at the end of your function:

```
def insertion_sort():
    f = open("integers.txt", "r")

    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    print(lines)
    print(type(lines[0]))
    results = list(map(int, lines))
    print(type(results[0]))
    results.sort()
    print(results)
    return results  # <- Add this line
```

Then, use the returned list by changing:
`insertion_sort()` to `value = insertion_sort()`

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use function sorted

```
value = sorted(results)
```

And you may not use list(map(int, lines))) you can pass map object to the sorted, so code will be like this:

```
results = sorted(map(int,lines))
```

And full example will be like this:

```
f=open("integers.txt", "r")
lines = f.read().splitlines()
sorted_lines = sorted(map(int,lines))
file_to_save_to = open("results.txt", "w")
for line in sorted_lines:
     file_to_save_to.write(str(line))
file_to_save_to.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it would be great if you would change your function to receive a parameter (list of ints), and return sorted list instead of None (as it is right now)

```
def insertion_sort(T):
    return sorted(T)


f=open("integers.txt", "r")
lines = f.read().splitlines()
results = list(map(int,lines))
value = insertion_sort(results)

file_to_save_to = open("results.txt", "w")
file_to_save_to.write(str(value))
file_to_save_to.close()
```